# Which is right in past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect

I want to know which structure is right when forming past perfect tense?

> "She was very sad because she hadn't got the package."

**or**

> "She was very sad because she hadn't gotten the package."

As far as I know, including Had + past participle is a must when forming past perfect tense. So basically the "She had gotten" must be the right choice but my English guide book suggests the "She had got" is right and I asked from a few of friends and they said that the "She had got" is ok and normal in British English. I don't which one should I go with and it is so important for me to know the difference since I deal with academic lessons and writings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the verb 'get' in the sentences presented implies to receive.

In AE, the past participle of get is 'gotten", whereas in BE, it's "got"

So if you follow AE, you should use gotten. On the other hand, if you follow BE, you should use got.

Besides, you say you don't have or haven't got in BE when you talk about possessions, relationships, etc., whereas in AE, you usually say you don't have.  If you want to convey this sense, you can rephrase the sentence as follows:

She was very sad because she hadn't got/didn't have the package (BE).

She was very sad because she didn't have the package (AE & BE).

Answer (score 1):

This first sentence is ambiguous in British English, because "have got" can mean possessing something. Here are some ways of rephrasing it:

> She was very sad because she didn't receive the package.
>   She was very sad because she didn't get the package.

...meaning the package didn't arrive, or:

> She was very sad because she didn't have the package.

... meaning it wasn't in her possession